# Getting error while running R code "connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER" . I need to connect R to oracle

Tags: r, database, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I am trying to run below code:

```
library("RODBC")

idisc_ODBC <- odbcConnect("TEST",'sys', "oracle123",
                       believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time = 1)
```

Also find attached screenshot for [oracle db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLWPe.png)

Running the R code getting error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=TEST;UID=sys;PWD=oracle123", believeNRows = FALSE,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 28009, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=TEST;UID=sys;PWD=oracle123", believeNRows = FALSE,  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R.

First of all, why are you connecting as SYS? It (along with SYSTEM) owns the database; it is *special* and - if you don't know what you are doing, you might destroy the database. Leave SYS and SYSTEM alone. Create another user and do whatever you are doing in its schema.

As of your question: username is (obviously SYS), its password is oracle123. If that's so, try with

```
idisc_ODBC <- odbcConnect("TEST",'sys as sysdba', "oracle123",
```

It works, as far as Oracle is concerned; have a look at this demonstration - I'm connecting to the database as SYS, running SQL*Plus at command prompt:

```
C:\>sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Pet Stu 23 20:05:40 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

See the first line? `sys as sysdba`. Hopefully, it'll work with R as well. Though, once again: don't use SYS. There are users in the database you might be using instead. If you look at the list:

```
SQL> select * from all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- --------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 29.05.14
SCOTT                                  79 06.09.18      --> this
IMPORTER                               76 06.09.18
MIKE                                   71 30.03.18
APEX_040000                            47 29.05.14
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 29.05.14
FLOWS_FILES                            44 29.05.14
HR                                     43 29.05.14      --> this
<snip>
```

two obvious choices are SCOTT and HR. If you don't know their passwords, set them as

```
SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Now your connection would look like

```
idisc_ODBC <- odbcConnect("TEST",'scott', "tiger",
```

and it should work (of course, if the syntax is correct; I don't know why username is enclosed into single quotes, but password into double ones - I hope you do know it).